# Почему моя программа лагает после 5-ого повторения не грузит Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, математика, python-3.7

Ребят, скажите пожалуйста, почему моя программа лагает после повторения? Мой код:

```
from random import randint as rand_digit

first_digit_list = []
second_digit_list = []

count_of_correct_answer = 0
max_answers = 10

this_answer_number = 1

while this_answer_number <= max_answers:
    first_digit_random = rand_digit(1, 9)
    if not first_digit_random in first_digit_list:
        first_digit_list.append(first_digit_random)
        second_digit_random = rand_digit(1, 9)
        if not second_digit_random in second_digit_list:
            second_digit_list.append(second_digit_random)
            user_input_math = input(f"Ответ - {first_digit_random} * {second_digit_random} = ")
            if user_input_math == (f"{first_digit_random * second_digit_random}"):
                count_of_correct_answer += 1
                this_answer_number += 1

print(f"Правильных ответов: {count_of_correct_answer}/{max_answers}")
input()
```

**Что в консоли:**

```
Ответ - 1 * 5 = 5
Ответ - 3 * 8 = 24
Ответ - 7 * 6 = 42
Ответ - 8 * 1 = 8
Ответ - 4 * 9 = 36
Ответ - 5 * 2 = 10
```

(Последние цифры на конце каждой строчки это мой input())

То есть, в чём проблема. Он не до конца завершил свою программу, а дальше не грузит. Что делать?
Это моя программа или что-то другое?

P.s: программу делал я брату, чтобы он выучил таблицу умножения, а вопрос про программирование!

Comment: план б: после каждой строчки в цикле написать 'принт номер строки' и будет выдно перед какой строкой затык. и эту строку уже обдумывать

Comment: нашёл затык, там перед строкой if not first_digit_random нормально, а эта строка в затыке. А как исправить?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Программа "не грузит" из-за того, что у вас после n-ого прохода не удовлетворяются два условия, а конкретно:

```python
if not first_digit_random in first_digit_list:
...
    if not second_digit_random in second_digit_list:
...
```

Так что я предлагаю такое решение задачи:

```python
from random import randint, choice

first_digit_list = [i for i in range(11)]
second_digit_list = [i for i in range(11)]

count_of_correct_answer = 0
max_answers = 10


for i in range(max_answers):
    first_digit_random = choice(first_digit_list)
    second_digit_random = choice(second_digit_list)

    user_input_math = input(f"Ответ - {first_digit_random} * {second_digit_random} = ")
    if user_input_math == (f"{first_digit_random * second_digit_random}"):
        count_of_correct_answer += 1

print(f"Правильных ответов: {count_of_correct_answer}/{max_answers}")
input()
```

Answer (score 1):

твой код не "не грузит", а попадает в бесконечный цикл, из-за того что
длина first_digit_list растёт быстрее, чем this_answer_number. Выведи first_digit_list и поймёшь почему.

Answer (score 0):

В процессе выполнения программы один из списков оказывается заполнен всеми числами от 1 до 9, в результате условие if not first_digit_random in first_digit_list: (или второй if) не срабатывают и программа зависает - не может сделать .append() и продвинуться дальше.

Comment: он не до конца заполняет. Вот в чём прикол, он у меня не успевает заполнится как уже не грузит...

Comment: попробуйте сделать print() списка после каждой строки с append и посмотрите, что получается в процессе работы. Программа зависает как только длина одного из списков становится равна 9 и в него уже не добавить из-за условия.